# Existence of absolutely continuous measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Does there exists a finite measure $\mu$ on the $\sigma-$algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu << m$ and $m <<\mu$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure?

My attempt is to use the Radon-Nikodym theorem to arrive at a contradiction but I am stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about $\mu(A)=\int_A\exp(-x^2)m(dx)$?

Comment: How do we compute $\mu(E)$ if $m(E)=0$?

Comment: I realized that I think your $\mu$ will actually work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick your favorite positive function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R},\mathrm dm(x))$ and define
$$
\mu(A)=\int_A f(x)\;\mathrm d m(x)
$$
for $A$ a Lebesgue measurable set.

Comment: Hmmm, should $f$ be necessarily integrable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @JohnThompson I missed the important caveat that the measure be finite! Of course yes take $f$ to be $L^1$

Comment: I agree that any such integrable $f$ will work. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnThompson sure thing. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

How about defining the function
$$
\phi(x) = {\pi \over 2} + \arctan(x)
$$
and defining, for every interval $A = ]a, b[$ in $\mathbb{R}$, even if $a = -\infty$ or $b = +\infty$ or both,
$$
\mu(A) = \phi(b) - \phi(a),
$$
taking the necessary limits if the interval is not bounded?

The idea of $g(x)$ is to map unbounded intervals to bounded ones, guaranteeing the constructed measure will be finite.

I suppose $g(x) = \phi'(x)$ can be seen as a Radon-Nykodym derivative that will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mu(A) =\sum \frac {m(A \cap (-n,n))} {2^{n}}$.